# Auto refreshing multiple divs MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to update a column of data in a table in MVC view.
This is the View that I want to update.

```
<table class="table">
<tr>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CurrentTemperature)
    </th>

    <th></th>
</tr>
@{int i = 1;}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td align="center" @*id="@("current"+i)" data-id="@item.ID"*@>
            <div id="@("current"+i)" data-id="@item.ID">
                @{Html.RenderAction("TemperatureUpdateDeviceList", new { idDevice = item.ID });}
            </div>       
        </td>

    </tr>
    i++;
}
</table>
```

I wrote a simple script in order to update the divs. Just for trying I decided to update only the 4th div with id= current4.

```
$(function () {

    setInterval(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("TemperatureUpdateDeviceList")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { idDevice: id},
            }).success(function (partialView) {
                $('#current4').html(partialView);
            });
    },3000);
});
```

Using this method I can't perform a correct request because the generated URL is not correct. How to have a correct URL?

Notice that TemperatureUpdateDeviceList function is defined as:

```
public PartialViewResult TemperatureUpdateDeviceList(int idDevice)
    {            
       return PartialView(temperatureModel);
    }
```

Comment: What's the url that `Url.Action()` is generating? And what's the url that you're looking for?

Comment: Your base url is correct, but your `id` wont be (`$(this)` is not the element). There is no need to give you divs an id attribute. You can just get the all the divs using a class name and use a `$.each()` loop where you will be able to use `$(this).data('id')` and `$(this).html(partialView)`

Comment: It doesn't return the parameter: idDevice

Comment: Apart from Stephens correct observation - Is the js-snippet placed in a razor-enabled view (i.e. not in a js-file)?

Comment: Well , the js is in the same cshtml file as the view

Comment: So it is not needed to have different IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use of `var id = $(this).attr('data-id');` will not pass the `data-id` value because `$(this)` is not your `<div>` element. If you want to update all your elements, then change the html to

```
<div class="container" data-id="@item.ID">
    @{Html.RenderAction("TemperatureUpdateDeviceList", new { idDevice = item.ID });}
</div>
```

Note the `id` attribute is not necessary. Then in the script use

```
var url = '@Url.Action("TemperatureUpdateDeviceList")';

setInterval(function () {
    $('.container').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var div = $(this);
        $.get(url, { idDevice: id}, function(partialView) {
            div.html(partialView);
        });
    });
},3000);
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you!